# Apache Ignite - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, ignite

this is my last attempt to configure **Apache Ignite 2.0** to work with Cassandra as persistence layer and ODBC as query layer.

ODBC configuration is ok, I am able to put and get data in the cache with sql, but when I plug in Cassandra (version 3.9 via docker image) as persistence layer I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=1262449073]
```

I tried googling around for this exception but got no useful hint.

Here's my **Ignite configuration**:

```
        boolean persistence = true;

        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        CacheConfiguration<String, ValueClass> configuration = new CacheConfiguration<String, ValueClass>();

        configuration.setName("test-cache");
        configuration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, ValueClass.class);

        if(persistence){
            //  Configuring Cassandra's persistence
            DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
            dataSource.setContactPoints("172.17.0.2");
            RoundRobinPolicy robinPolicy = new RoundRobinPolicy();
            dataSource.setLoadBalancingPolicy(robinPolicy);
            dataSource.setReadConsistency("ONE");
            dataSource.setWriteConsistency("ONE");
            String persistenceSettingsXml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(persistenceSettingsConfig), "utf-8");
            KeyValuePersistenceSettings persistenceSettings = new KeyValuePersistenceSettings(persistenceSettingsXml);
            CassandraCacheStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CassandraCacheStoreFactory();
            cacheStoreFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            cacheStoreFactory.setPersistenceSettings(persistenceSettings);
            configuration.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);
            configuration.setWriteThrough(true);
            configuration.setReadThrough(true);
            configuration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
        }

        //  Setting cache configuration
        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(configuration);

        //  Configuring ODBC
        OdbcConfiguration odbcConfig = new OdbcConfiguration();
        odbcConfig.setMaxOpenCursors(100);
        cfg.setOdbcConfiguration(odbcConfig);

        //  Starting Ignite
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

**ValueClass:**

```
public class ValueClass implements Serializable{
    @QuerySqlField
    private Integer numberOne;
    @QuerySqlField
    private Integer numberTwo;

    public Integer getNumberOne(){ return numberOne; }

    public Integer getNumberTwo(){ return numberTwo; }

    public void setNumberOne(Integer value){
        numberOne = value;
    }
    public void setNumberTwo(Integer value){
        numberTwo = value;
    }
}
```

**Persistence configuration:**

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="odbc_test" ttl="86400">
    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>

    <tableOption>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOption>

    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key" />

    <valuePersistence class="com.riccamini.ignite.ValueClass" strategy="POJO">
        <value name="numberOne" column="number_one"/>
        <value name="numberTwo" column="number_two"/>
    </valuePersistence>
</persistence>
```

**Complete stack trace**:

```
SEVERE: <test-cache> Unexpected exception during cache update
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Runtime failure on search row: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$SearchRow@6380d269
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:1615)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:925)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:1693)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2386)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1792)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.sendSingleRequest(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:440)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:651)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2345)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putIfAbsent(GridCacheAdapter.java:2720)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.doInsert(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:829)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.executeUpdateStatement(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:369)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFields(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFieldsTwoStep(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1659)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1659)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1657)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryTwoStep(GridQueryProcessor.java:1657)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(OdbcRequestHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcRequestHandler.handle(OdbcRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcNioListener.onMessage(OdbcNioListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcNioListener.onMessage(OdbcNioListener.java:33)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=1262449073]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:701)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1745)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1704)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectContext.java:273)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:161)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:148)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1730)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:555)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.update(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4404)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4226)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3966)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.invokeClosure(BPlusTree.java:2966)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.access$6200(BPlusTree.java:2860)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invokeDown(BPlusTree.java:1696)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:1585)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=1262449073]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:385)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:692)
    ... 53 more

Jun 28, 2017 10:02:41 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=2, req=OdbcQueryExecuteRequest [cacheName=test-cache, sqlQry=INSERT INTO valueclass (_key, numberone, numbertwo) VALUES ('testkey2', 10, 10), args=[]]]
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=INSERT INTO valueclass (_key, numberone, numbertwo) VALUES ('testkey2', 10, 10), params=[]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:818)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(OdbcRequestHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcRequestHandler.handle(OdbcRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcNioListener.onMessage(OdbcNioListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.OdbcNioListener.onMessage(OdbcNioListener.java:33)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=INSERT INTO valueclass (_key, numberone, numbertwo) VALUES ('testkey2', 10, 10), params=[]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1662)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1659)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1657)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryTwoStep(GridQueryProcessor.java:1657)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:806)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CachePartialUpdateCheckedException: Failed to update keys (retry update if possible).: [testkey2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.onPrimaryError(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:397)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.onPrimaryResponse(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:250)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture$1.apply(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:303)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture$1.apply(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:300)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1885)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.sendSingleRequest(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:440)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:651)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2345)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putIfAbsent(GridCacheAdapter.java:2720)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.doInsert(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:829)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.executeUpdateStatement(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:369)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFields(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFieldsTwoStep(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1659)
    ... 18 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to update keys on primary node.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.UpdateErrors.addFailedKeys(UpdateErrors.java:124)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicUpdateResponse.addFailedKeys(GridNearAtomicUpdateResponse.java:342)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1883)
        ... 32 more
        Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Runtime failure on search row: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$SearchRow@6380d269
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:1615)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:925)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:326)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:1693)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2386)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1792)
            ... 32 more
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=1262449073]
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:701)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1745)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1704)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:794)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectContext.java:273)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:161)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:148)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1730)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:555)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.update(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4404)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4226)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3966)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.invokeClosure(BPlusTree.java:2966)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.access$6200(BPlusTree.java:2860)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invokeDown(BPlusTree.java:1696)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.database.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:1585)
            ... 37 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=1262449073]
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:385)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:335)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:692)
            ... 53 more
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: which version of Ignite do you use?

Comment: Version 2.0. I'll update the question

Comment: On which operation you got this exception? on cache.query()?

Comment: I get the exception executing an insert query using the ODBC driver on the fields _key, numberOne, numberTwo

Comment: Also, could you share full stacktrace? It's hard to understand why this exception was thrown without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to turn on `isStoreKeepBinary` in cache settings - like this; please note the last line:

```
if (persistence){
        //  Configuring Cassandra's persistence
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        // ...here go the rest of your settings as they appear now...
        configuration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);

        configuration.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
    }
```

This setting forces Ignite to avoid binary deserialization when working with underlying cache store.

Comment: The issue got resolved. I am getting a different error involving the execution of the query `org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to get value of the field 'numberOne' from the instance  of 'class org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl'`. I am going to work on that, thank you.