# Apache Ignite - Cassandra persistence issue

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, ignite

This question is strictly related to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781672/apache-ignite-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-unknown-pair).

Quick summary: I am struggling to configure Cassandra as persistence layer for my Ignite 2.0 cache. It fails with write-behind operations because of:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

I tried to play with the schema on Cassandra, fields configuration in the persistence settings, cache properties etc. but I am not able to overcome that. The following is last configuration I tried:

**Persistence settings:**

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="odbc_test" ttl="86400">
    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>
    <tableOption>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOption>
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key"/>
    <valuePersistence class="com.riccamini.ignite.ValueClass" strategy="POJO"/>
</persistence>
```

**ValueClass:**

```
public class ValueClass implements Serializable{
    @QuerySqlField
    private int numberOne;
    @QuerySqlField
    private int numberTwo;

    public int getNumberOne(){ return numberOne;}

    public int getNumberTwo(){ return numberTwo;}

    public void setNumberOne(int value){
        numberOne = value;
    }

    public void setNumberTwo(int value){
        numberTwo = value;
    }
}
```

**Cassandra's table:**

```
CREATE TABLE ignite.odbc_test (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    numberone int,
    numbertwo int);
```

**Ignite's configuration:**

```
boolean persistence = true;

IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
CacheConfiguration<String, ValueClass> configuration = new CacheConfiguration<String, ValueClass>();

configuration.setName("test-cache");
configuration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, ValueClass.class);

if(persistence){
    //  Configuring Cassandra's persistence
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setContactPoints("172.17.0.2");
    RoundRobinPolicy robinPolicy = new RoundRobinPolicy();
    dataSource.setLoadBalancingPolicy(robinPolicy);
    dataSource.setReadConsistency("ONE");
    dataSource.setWriteConsistency("ONE");
    String persistenceSettingsXml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(persistenceSettingsConfig), "utf-8");
    KeyValuePersistenceSettings persistenceSettings = new KeyValuePersistenceSettings(persistenceSettingsXml);
    CassandraCacheStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CassandraCacheStoreFactory();
    cacheStoreFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    cacheStoreFactory.setPersistenceSettings(persistenceSettings);
    configuration.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);
    configuration.setWriteThrough(true);
    configuration.setReadThrough(true);
    configuration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
    configuration.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
    }


//  Setting cache configuration
cfg.setCacheConfiguration(configuration);

//  Configuring ODBC
OdbcConfiguration odbcConfig = new OdbcConfiguration();
odbcConfig.setMaxOpenCursors(100);
cfg.setOdbcConfiguration(odbcConfig);

//  Starting Ignite
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

**Complete stack trace:**

```
SEVERE: Failed to process 1 of 1 elements, during BULK_WRITE operation with Cassandra
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to execute Cassandra BULK_WRITE operation
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.execute(CassandraSessionImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore.writeAll(CassandraCacheStore.java:333)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore.updateStore(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:804)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore.applyBatch(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:720)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore.access$2400(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:75)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore$Flusher.flushCacheCoalescing(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:1135)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore$Flusher.body(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:1006)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to get value of the field 'numberOne' from the instance  of 'class org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl' class
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PojoField.getValueFromObject(PojoField.java:165)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PersistenceController.bindValues(PersistenceController.java:450)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PersistenceController.bindKeyValue(PersistenceController.java:203)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore$4.bindStatement(CassandraCacheStore.java:347)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore$4.bindStatement(CassandraCacheStore.java:333)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.execute(CassandraSessionImpl.java:230)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PojoField.getValueFromObject(PojoField.java:147)
    ... 13 more
```

Thank you for all the help provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you set this:

> configuration.setStoreKeepBinary(true);

Set it to false (which is default), deploy POJO classes on server nodes and it will work. Current implementation can't work with binary objects directly, this will be improved in the scope of this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5270

Comment: Thank you, but setting it to true was suggested as solution to the error reported in the linked question. Any other suggestion (maybe solving the previous error)?

Comment: I tried writing to Ignite with both the Ignite API and the REST interface, and data is correctly persisted into Cassandra. The particular combination of ODBC and Cassandra persistence is still problematic [Valentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604242/valentin-kulichenko). Any idea?

Comment: I doubt these two things are related to each other. `storeKeepBinary` is server side configuration which can't be affected by client API you're using. So I think there is something else causing issues. Can you create a simple GitHub project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thank you, I did some changes to test also the native API and the JDBC driver and now it works. Honestly, I don't know exactly what it was, but I am fine with it.